# jQuery - Use quick filter from ajax results

Tags: jquery

I've downloaded jquery plugin [Quick Filter for Jquery](https://github.com/bdelespierre/jquery-quickfilter) and I tried to use it for ajax post results but it's not working. Does anyone have idea what could be wrong or how to modify it?

Direct link to jquery plugin: 
https://github.com/bdelespierre/jquery-quickfilter/blob/master/jquery.quickfilter-0.0.1.js

This is how jquery request look like:

```
    $('#cam').change(function(e){
    serializedData = $("#thisid").serialize() ;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/results.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#cam-list').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: make sure you append the ajax result first to a DOM (body) and use the filter plugins after.... need to post some more information to get some help...

Comment: You're not calling the quickFilter script at all? See `$('#list').quickFilter(options);`

Comment: Thanks for advice bipen, but could you give me some more info about appending the ajax result first to DOM. Thank you.

Comment: Pez yes I'm calling it (just forgot to post that line) and it's working for static results. But not for live ones.